# Firefox import PEM certificate chain fails

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate

I am trying to import a cert chain into Firefox 31.3 ESR. The origin chain is a p7b file which I have converted with OpenSSL to PEM format. `curl` happily accepts that chain and establishes the connection. Firefox however imports only the first cert from the file. The rest gets ignored.

Do I have to import every single one?
The chain is question is available here: http://www.siemens.com/pki/siemens_ca_certificates.p7b

The stupid workaround I applied wa to split the PEM file as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/391397/116898) and import every single cert :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a chain; it's an agglomeration of CA certificates containing three roots, of which only one looks "interesting", a bunch of subordinate CAs, and two bridge certs (to versions of Cybertrust). Just as one might infer from the URL.

HTTPS (and SSL/TLS) servers are supposed to provide the complete cert chain up to but not necessarily including the root, and it should never be necessary to install any non-root cert as trusted in Firefox. If you look at the Firefox provided store -- and Windows, and Java, and probably others -- you'll see that most of the trusted certs are roots, although there are a few exceptions. (OTOH certs that are explicitly *distrusted* frequently are not roots.) Bridge certs are useful mostly for a server to use with clients that *don't* have the needed root(s), usually a new root against an older client.

Thus it should be enough to install the three roots, and quite possibly only the one for "Trust Center RootCA v2.0". Plus *maybe* the bridge for "Internet CA v1.0" to "Baltimore Cybertrust" (in Servers tab not Authoritites) if your servers use that, since there does not seem to be a root for it.

Yes, each one must be installed separately, at least using Firefox. I believe there are commandline/standalone utilities available for NSS, the Mozilla module that does cryptography and SSL/TLS used by Firefox among others. I expect these tools probably can do something as basic as add a cert. They aren't included in the Windows install of Firefox; I don't know about other platforms. NSS is opensource, so presumably you could download and compile it yourself, but I'll bet that would be much more work than just clicking the GUI a few times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am aware of NSS' `certutil` but did want to try GUI in Firefox first. Question still remains, why curl does happily eat the entire file? The curl man page says that even compiled against NSS this should work and it does by default on Red Hat.

Comment: OpenSSL's API for the (SSL/TLS) truststore supports either a file of concatenated PEM certs, or a directory of PEM files each a *single* cert with link (or name) based on a hash of the Subject. curl using OpenSSL supports this, although it calls the concat file `--cacert` instead of `*{ca,CA}file` as OpenSSL does. For a concat file all the certs are loaded into memory but only the one(s) needed for a given server connection is(are) actually used. I don't know what curl using NSS does. ...

Comment: ... The Firefox GUI allows you to view and set some flags for the cert while importing, which only works for one cert. Supporting multiple certs per file would make it more complex; I don't know why the developers didn't do that, but I'd guess because it would be even more confusing for the vast majority of users who already don't understand crypto and PKI.